# SimpleFacebook gives me nullPointerException

Tags: android-simple-facebook

**CODE**

```
SimpleFacebook simpleFacebook;
simpleFacebook = SimpleFacebook.getInstance(this);
```

Above is the part of code. When I used above object to get user profile info, it gave `Nullpointer Exception`. What is my problem?

Comment: I don't see the code of getting profile.., Can you share the stacktrace or the part of code you use to get profile?

Comment: Sorry for late comment. The problem solved itself. Anyway, thanks for your attention.